# How to get SSRS report to show Downtime per user correctly

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, reporting-services, reportmanager

I have created a report in SSRS which displays data from the below table.
This table groups data by the hour.

[image]

the the report sums of the total quantities each user did per hour, then with a totals colum at the end for the whole day

[image]

below is a preview of the report

[image]

my issue is, for the column 'DownTime', this shows the time between the current time and the last time each user did something.

When I add the column Downtime to my SSRS report, it is adding up the downtime for each time the person appears in the table. I only want this column to fetch the the number from downtime once for each user.

For example "bob" might have 5 minutes since he last did something, so the table will show Downtime 5 for "bob".

However if bob has many actions overs several hours so there are 6 columns with "bob" in it in the table, then my column "downtime" on my ssrs report will show 30 minutes downtime (5minutes x 6 entries in the table).

My downtime column is not set to sum(downtime) it's only downtime, i'm not sure how i can get the report to show only the value once and not multiple it for every time they appear in the table, can anyone help, I can't think what to do to get what i want?

thank you

Comment: *"My downtime column is not set to sum(downtime) it's only downtime"* The bottom row in your screenshot has `SUM(Downtime)`.

Comment: And now it works, sweet lord